# want to convert date format 24/05/2021 to 24/May/2021 on using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date `24/05/2021`, I want to convert its date format to `24/May/2021` using `Javascript` or `jquery` as user leaves `textbox`, my **client don't want to use date picker**, he just want to type dates straight and auto convert date as he leaves the textbox, like he does in excel.

I find many ways but got nothing, I know how to do it server side but it has to be done at client side.

Comment: Do you have ability to use any third-party libraries?
I have an idea but it requires library.

Comment: jquery may have a library for dates - you're better off using *javascript* `Date` methods, or [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) where you can do such things easily

Comment: @capchuck - don't say momentjs :p

Comment: @Bravo I was thinking about `date-fns`.
It is quite simple: parse date from string and format it. :)

Comment: @capchuck - good choice - though, plain 'ol javascript much less hassle ... simple lookup of the month in an array :p

Comment: `I find many ways but got nothing` - like what?

Comment: @Bravo sure. Is there any simple way to parse date string like `24/05/2021` to `Date`  without dancing with regex and all the stuff?

Comment: @capchuck OP never said he wanted a `Date` object :p

Comment: @Bravo Sure, but your idea with `Intl` sounds interesting for me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said that **client don't want to use date picker**, you need to define the format that user will input.

You can split every segment and then format the month, then put the value in the `input` element's value on DOM.

As for the example below, I assume that the user uses `/` as the separator for the input.

```js
function formatDate(val){
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  
  var parts = val.split('/');
  var d = parts[0];
  var y = parts[2];
  var m = months[parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1];
  
  var inp = document.querySelector('#inp');
  if(/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/.test(val)){
    inp.value = `${d}/${m}/${y}`;
  } else inp.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" required pattern="[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}" onchange="formatDate(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: If I leave input empty after some edits it shows me `/undefined/undefined`

Comment: @capchuck Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer with the check.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to check if the date inputted is correct or not, if it is correct then you can change its format, otherwise you can show error. Here is the code:

```js
const month = ["January","February","March","April","May","une","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

const dateregex = /^[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-1]?[0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/

class DateField {
    constructor(id) {
    this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
    this.elemInp = this.elem.children[1];
    this.elemError = this.elem.children[0];
    this.date = null;
    this.elemInp.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        console.log(dateregex.test(this.elemInp.value), dateregex, this.elemInp.value);
        if (!dateregex.test(this.elemInp.value)) {
        this.showError();
        this.date = null;
        return;
      }
      var datesplits = this.elemInp.value.split('/');
      
        this.date = new Date();
      this.date.setYear(parseInt(datesplits[2],10));
      this.date.setDate(parseInt(datesplits[0],10));
      this.date.setMonth(parseInt(datesplits[1],10) - 1);
        
      var newDateString = this.date.getDate() + '/' + month[this.date.getMonth()] + '/' + this.date.getFullYear();
      this.elemInp.value = newDateString;
      this.removeError();
      
    });
    this.elemInp.addEventListener('focus', () => {
        if (this.date !== null && !isNaN(this.date.getTime())) {
        var newDateString = this.date.getDate() + '/' + (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.date.getFullYear();
        this.elemInp.value = newDateString;
      }
    });
  }
  
  showError() {
    this.elemError.innerText = "date is invalid";
  }
  
  removeError() {
    this.elemError.innerText = "";
  }
}

var d1 = new DateField("dateContainer");
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>try js</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="dateContainer">
      <p style="color: red;"></p>
      <input type="text" id="date" />
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on "/" and then with the second array element you make an array with the months like this:

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
```

Then you split your string on "/" and get a date like:

```
const split = document.querySelector("#input").split("/");

const date = new Date(`${split[1]}/${split[0]}/${split[2]}`);
```

And finally:

```
const month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
```

The HTML is gonna be something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input" required onchange="formatDate(this.value)"/>
```